# Photoshop CC won't switch from Artboard Document Type option when creating new document

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Whenever I try to create a new document in Photoshop CC it always creates a new 'Artboard' type document with in-determined width and height.

I've tried to update PS with no changes.

Now, the only way I can create new documents is to open old ones, delete everything and save them as a new file.

Would anyone know what can be done about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Choosing a **custom** document type in the legacy "New Document" interface will get you a classic document, choosing any of the presets will create an artboard.

[image: screenshot of New Document interface with artboard checkbox not selected]

If you use the new "New Document" interface there is a checkbox for wether or not you want to create a new document as an artboard.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to File -> New, select Document Type, select a different preset or custom. You probably have your document type on Artboard.

[image: photoshop document type]

Comment: No, that's exactly my problem. I switch it from Artboard to something else but it still creates the new document as an Artboard type